# How do I playback SVG animated stickers in my iOS app like Viber does?

Tags: ios, animation, svg, xamarin

How do I playback SVG animated stickers in my iOS app like Viber does?

If you are not familiar with Viber, you can see examples of SVG animated stickers from the Viber app at this link:

http://www.tbyrne.org/viber-animated-svgs

Note: I use Xamarin framework to develop my apps in C#, but any native (Swift, Objective-C) solution is good too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: The site you linked is down/not responding so I do not know what those SVG files look like*

The fastest way is to embed a `UIWebView` into your app and than you can load local (resource embedded) or remote SVGs. They can be wrapped in html and using JavaScript-based animation techniques, CSS animation or SVG/SMIL based animations:

#### i.e.:

```
WebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("https://imgh.us/LoveDota.svg")));
```

Depending upon your app's requirements and the SVG that you are using, this will be the fastest way to include animated SVGs. The ability to embedded `UIWebView`s into any view and/or controls' subviews works really well. And since you have access to the DOM, you can manipulate the SVG on the fly.

#### LoveDota.svg playing within iOS WebKit:

[image: LoveDota.svg]

I would recommend wrapping the SVG content in an html file so you can control the scaling, add Javascript event callbacks into your app, etc...

Note: If you need to quickly test content and fit it to your `UIWebView` set the `ScalesPageToFit` property:

```
WebView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```

The "slower", coding required :-) , way is to use the great [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) project via a sharpie binding project. It does not `directly` support SVG animations but depending upon the toolset(s) that you are using for your SVG animation development, exporting SVG and using SVGKit to output a series of [CoreAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) layers is amazing and gets you away from using `WebKit` (and its SVG interactive DOM event quirks).

#### Animated SVG Progress Bar on top of Xamarin's `SpriteKit` example:

[image]

Comment: FWIW the site's images are SMIL animated SVG.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for that info.,. (is that site responding for you? Still nothing here or through a remote proxy)

Comment: It hangs, but the images work e.g. http://www.tbyrne.org/portfolio/viber/1705.svg

Comment: Thanks, still nothing even with your direct link... I try later, just interested to see them. Thanks again